# python multiprocessing set spawning process to wait

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Is it possible to spawn some processes and set the spawning process to wait until the spawned processes finish? Bellow is an example I have used.

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import sys

def daemon():
    p = multiprocessing.current_process()
    print 'Starting:', p.name, p.pid
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'Exiting :', p.name, p.pid
    sys.stdout.flush()

def non_daemon():
    p = multiprocessing.current_process()
    print 'Starting:', p.name, p.pid
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print 'Exiting :', p.name, p.pid
    sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = multiprocessing.Process(name='daemon', target=daemon)
    d.daemon = True

    n = multiprocessing.Process(name='non-daemon', target=non_daemon)
    n.daemon = False

    print "start main"
    d.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    n.start()
    print "stop main"
```

will print

```
start main
Starting: daemon 2809
stop main
Starting: non-daemon 2810
Exiting : non-daemon 2810
```

while I would like to have:

```
start main
messages from other services 
stop main
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`d.join()`
[will block the main thread](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) until `d` finishes.
So, to get the order of print statements you desire, put the `join`s before `print "stop main"`:

```
print "start main"
d.start()
time.sleep(1)
n.start()
d.join()
n.join()
print "stop main"
```

Comment: @danizgod: `join` is the usual name for this kind of action, so you will find also `join` in `Thread` and in `Queue`