# multiprocessing python is it possible to send to the pool a job sequentially

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to send jobs to a Pool one by one (due to memory limits I cannot use map). Is it possible for the pool to digest if it has available workers and otherwise to wait?
e.g. can I do something like this?

`p = Pool(n_workers)
for item in list:
    p.work_on_this(item)`

where `work_on_this` sends the job if the pool has more workers available and otherwise wait until it does.

Comment: You might be looking for something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909132/python-multiprocessing-set-spawning-process-to-wait. With this I think some logic can be built.

Comment: Are you sure you can't use `map`? Setting `chunksize=1` will send the jobs one-by-one.

Comment: How about `imap` instead of `map`?

Comment: have you considered this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor  or https://pythonhosted.org/futures/#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor based on your python version ? This would make your life and implementation really easier.

Comment: You can add a "callback" to the pool, which is called at the end of the process, like `pool.apply_async(func, args=(data), callback=f_callback)` and then in `f_callback` you could re-trigger another job for the pool

Answer (score 0):

The way the problem can be solved is by using a semaphore initialized with the number of workers. You acquire and release the semaphore before feeding the pool and after a worker has completed the task.

Here's an example working with Python 2.6 or greater.

```
from threading import Semaphore
from multiprocessing import Pool


def TaskManager:
    def __init__(self, processes):
        self.pool = Pool(processes=processes)
        self.workers = Semaphore(processes)

    def new_task(self):
        """Start a new task, block if all workers are busy."""
        self.workers.acquire()
        self.pool.apply_async(function, callback=self.task_done)

    def task_done(self, results):
        """Called once task is done, releases the caller if blocked."""
        self.workers.release()
```